# Which date formats can I use when specifying the expiry date when setting a cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using a function which sets a cookie. This function allows the cookie name, the cookie value and an additional expiry date of the cookie to be passed into it.

```
function setCookie(name, value, exdate) {
    var c_value = escape(value) + 
      ((exdate === null || exdate === undefined) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate);
    document.cookie = name + "=" + c_value;
};
```

Usage:

```
setCookie("my-cookie-name","my-value","Sun, 15 Jul 2012 00:00:01 GMT");
```

I have used the function with the date format above and believe it is cross browser compatible as I have tested if the cookie remains after closing various browsers and reopening them. I discovered that there were problems when using a format like `"15 Jul 2012"`. This format worked for me during development in Firefox, but other browsers only seemed to set the cookie as a session cookie.

Should I stick to using just this format: `"Sun, 15 Jul 2012 00:00:01 GMT"` or are there other formats I could use for the expiry date that will work across the major browsers (IE 7-9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari)?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Based on testing and further reading into this, a date in a **UTC/GMT format is required by cookies** e.g. **Sun, 15 Jul 2012 00:00:01 GMT**

Therefore any dates in other formats such as **15 Jul 2012**, or **15/Jul/2012**, or **07/15/2012**, have to be passed as a `new Date` object and then through the `toUTCString()` or the `toGMTString()` function.

**therefore I have edited my function to the following:**

```
function setCookie(name, value, exdate) {
    //If exdate exists then pass it as a new Date and convert to UTC format
    (exdate) && (exdate = new Date(exdate).toUTCString());
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdate === null || exdate === undefined) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate);
    document.cookie = name + "=" + c_value;
};
```

Comment: can you add a link please, to show where you found the information ?

Comment: @kca apologies i'm 2 years late - and 10 years after posting this! :D from memory I think it was somewhere in mozilla's developer docs. I've just done some digging and found their docs now... it's mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie under 'Expires=<date>' and then that refers to the 'Date' section for 'required formatting' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date

Hope that is useful!

Answer (score 11):

[The syntax specified in rfc 6265 for generating Set-Cookie headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) uses
[`rfc1123-date = wkday "," SP date1 SP time SP "GMT"`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3.1) cookie date format and therefore `"Sun, 15 Jul 2012 00:00:01 GMT"` works.

If I understand it correctly, the [parsing algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1) would recognize other formats e.g.:  `00:00:01 15 jul 2012` but they should not be generated.

Comment: There are actually 3 formats supported with spaces (`Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT`), dashes (`Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT`), and "mixed up" (`Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994`)

Comment: @AlexisWilke click the link (with `rfc1123-date` in it)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that the other two are marked as deprecated. So you should only use the first one.

Answer (score 6):

Found the date format `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'`. May someone find is useful. Also very good reference [here](https://gist.github.com/y-gagar1n/8469484)