# Why can't I expire a cookie with JavaScript (not HttpOnly)

Tags: javascript, cookies, jquery-cookie

I've got a cookie being set in a framework I'm developing within via JavaScript (the framework appears to be using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). I'm developing within this framework but don't have access to the framework code and I want to delete a cookie via JavaScript (I do not have access to anything serverside within this framework).

Inspecting the cookie via Chrome, I can tell a lot about it:

```
"domain": "www.example.com", 
"expirationDate": 1667235180, 
"hostOnly": true, 
"httpOnly": false, 
"name": "my_cookie", 
"path": "/", 
"secure": false, 
"session": false, 
"storeId": "0", 
"value": "123456789"
```

It is hostOnly, but that should be fine as I am trying to remove from the same domain set in the domain field.

I'm trying to remove it using the following code:

```
function clearCookie(name, domain, path) {
      var domain = domain || document.domain;
      var path = path || "/";
      document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + +new Date + "; domain=" + domain + "; path=" + path;
};

clearCookie('my_cookie', 'www.example.com', '/');
```

When I do this however, it creates a new session cookie with a domain of ".www.example.com" (note the extra period) and doesn't delete the current cookie.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you use `jQuery.removeCookie`?

Comment: Even though that library is available, $.removeCookie doesn't work for me (defining the same name, path and domain). That's why I'm trying to find out what else could be affecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a problem with how you're setting the expiration. Setting cookies with JavaScript requires a UTC/GMT format for the date. See this related answer:

[Which date formats can I use when specifying the expiry date when setting a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136372/which-date-formats-can-i-use-when-specifying-the-expiry-date-when-setting-a-cook)

Comment: That explains why a session cookie is created instead (bad date information = no date information). For some reason I still cannot modify my cookie but I think this answers part of my question.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but I just ran into this and discovered the issue.

If you have a hostOnly cookie, do not specify the domain when you modify/expire it.

Most cookie handling libraries will auto-specify the domain if one is not provided, making it difficult, if not impossible, to edit a hostOnly cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually delete a cookie via javascript.  What you do is set the existing cookie to expire and then allow the browser to handle its destruction.  If you check the jquery-cookie source you can see that it actually has a function to destroy cookies that you could use here to simplify things.

The simple answer here is to use the existing frameworks remove function.

```
$.removeCookie(key)
```

Comment: Good point. That's my mistake in the title. I am simply trying to set a cookie to expire, not delete it.

Comment: I actually attempted that as well. It had no effect so I'm looking for more clues as to what's strange about this cookie.