# Create Cookie with Javascript and set expire time

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to create a cookie with javascript. This cookie will change dependent on what the user selects in a dropdown. I also want this cookie to expire after 5 min. I can create the cookie fine, but when I try to add the expires part. It adds the expires time to my cookie value.

```
var exp = new Date();
    var minutes = 5;
    exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));

     document.cookie ='orgunit' + "=" + document.getElementById('orgUnit').value + ";expires="+exp+';';
```

I'm sure this is a syntax error or something like that. Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Javascript cookie API is messy, I suggest you to use a library: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed the UTC String.  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136372/which-date-formats-can-i-use-when-specifying-the-expiry-date-when-setting-a-cook),

> the UTC/GMT format is required by cookies

.

Anyway, this works when I plug it into firefox

```
var exp = new Date();
var time = exp.getTime();
time += 5 * 60 * 1000;
exp.setTime(time);
document.cookie = 'orgunit=' + document.getElementById('orgUnit').value + 
'; expires=' + exp.toUTCString() + 
'; path=/';
```