# How do I set the cookie expiration date format when using sessions to create the cookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies

When I create a session with PHP's session functions `session_set_cookie_params`, and `session_start`. It seems that PHP is generating the date format for the cookie. The cookie header looks like this:

```
Set-Cookie SessionName=n5jfnnccfgdf0cofpj7rmogb801; expires=Fri, 22-Dec-2017 23:49:07 GMT; Max-Age=612000; path=/; domain=www.mydomain.com; secure; HttpOnly
```

But I believe the date should be formatted as: `Fri, 22 Dec 2017 22:15:36`, per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136372/which-date-formats-can-i-use-when-specifying-the-expiry-date-when-setting-a-cook) in order to be standards complaint.

Can this be changed in PHP, or is it a bug?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: PHP 5.5.9 on this server.

Comment: I wouldnt worry too much about it. PHP is a leading brand, and so far, its cookies work ;) You cannot actually change how it formats the date output (unless you dig into its source code and make a hack... er... mod). That post was more about avoiding the `/` usage, and making ambiguous dates like `5/1/2017` ... is that May, or January?!