# SvelteKit splits a set-cookie header when expiry is defined

Tags: cookies, svelte, sveltekit

On a SvelteKit endpoint, I am setting a cookie with an expiry using the [cookie package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) on NPM. The code is kind of like the following:

```js
export const post = async () => {
    const flavor = cookie.serialize('flavor', 'chocolate chip', {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60)
    })
    const headers = new Headers()
    headers.append('Set-Cookie', flavor)

    return new Response(null, {
        headers,
    })
}
```

On local environment, everything's dandy (: But in production, the expiry gets split into a different set-cookie header, pictured below:

[image: the expiry field is split, with the remainder on a new set-cookie header]

I am using the **Netlify Adapter**, and I've found that it seems to split on commas (relevant code below), but this is problematic as the [specification for date](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#http.date) demands a comma separating the day of the week and everything else.

```js
headers.forEach((value, key) => {
    if (key === 'set-cookie') {
        m[key] = value.split(', ');
    } else {
        h[key] = value;
    }
});
```

- [Netlify handler code, line 74](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/adapter-netlify/src/handler.js)

Am I missing something with setting cookies, or is this perhaps an unintended side-effect of the adapter?

Comment: This sounds like a bug - I'd open an issue on the SvelteKit repo.

Comment: This is probably because the implementation follows RFC 2109, which allows multiple cookies passed into the `Set-Cookie` header using commas as separators, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880047/is-it-possible-to-set-more-than-one-cookie-with-a-single-set-cookie

Comment: But @GeoffRich is right, if this impedes with setting the expiry dates on cookies (which also expect a comma, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136372/which-date-formats-can-i-use-when-specifying-the-expiry-date-when-setting-a-cook), then it is likely a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I can open up an issue!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that was addressed **[in this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4087)**.